# Reactive programming - value is greater than X for N seconds

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming

I have a stream `randStream` which emit random value every half second and `boolStream` which converts value from `randStream` into boolean.

```
let randStream = Kefir.fromPoll(500, () => Math.random())
let boolStream = Kefir.map((rand) => rand > 0.5)
```

I want to emit `true` when `boolStream` emits `true` for 5 seconds (in a row). Otherwise `emit` false.

I'm using [Kefir.js](https://pozadi.github.io/kefir/) library.

Do you have any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With given conditions when you know exact rate at which `randStream` emit numbers, it pretty easy to achieve with `.slidingWindow`:

```
let result = boolStream
  .slidingWindow(10, 10)
  .map(items => _.every(items))
  .skipDuplicates();
```

If you want it to work with any rate of events, you can try something like:

```
let result = boolStream
  .scan(({mostRecentFalse, latestValue}, bool) => {
    return bool ? 
      {mostRecentFalse, latestValue: true} : 
      {mostRecentFalse: Date.now(), lastValue: false}
  }, {mostRecentFalse: Date.now()})
  .changes()
  .map(({mostRecentFalse, latestValue}) => 
    latestValue && (Date.now() - mostRecentFalse > 5000))
  .skipDuplicates();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't write ES6 yet, but... the idea is, if your original stream is sampling once each half-second, five seconds of `true` is eleven trues in a row, right?

```
// generate random numbers
var randStream = Kefir.fromPoll(500, function() {
  return Math.random();
});

// make into booleans
var boolStream = randStream.map(function(rand) {
  return rand > 0.5;
});

// count trues in a row
var trueStreakStream = boolStream.scan(function(numTrue, curr) {
  return curr ? numTrue + 1 : 0;
}, 0);

// see when there's exactly 11 of them
var elevenTruesStream = trueStreakStream.filter(function(numTrue) {
  return numTrue == 11;
});

// react
elevenTruesStream.onValue(function(numTrue) {
  console.log("five seconds of true!");
});
```

EDIT: I just read your question again; if you want a stream that will be `true` if all of your last 5 seconds were `true`, then use `map` instead of `filter` (and `>=` rather than `==`):

```
var lastElevenAreTrueStream = trueStreakStream.map(function(numTrue) {
  return numTrue >= 11;
});
```